# window.opener.location.href permission denied. Possible cross domain issue?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I have a page that opens another page.

The first page has a url like
https://site1.myapplication.net/page2

The second page has a url like
https://site2.myapplication.net/page5

I'm guessing that this is cross domain, but I didn't think that was caused by subdomains (site1, site2) in the same domain.

My question is : is this a cross domain issue and how to fix it?  Last I checked CORS is not fully supported by some browsers.

EDIT:  Setting document.domain to "myapplication.net" seems to work but I have not tested this in more than 1 browser yet.